# Cannot detect Bluetooth device when connected to female receiver with PS4 Joystick

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, hc-05, baud-rate

I am trying to connect the Bluetooth transmitter to a female receiver via an Arduino Uno. The button blinks, but the Bluetooth is not visible in any device.
i want to connect PS4 controller using HC05
I am sharing my code below:

```cpp
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

/* Create object named bt of the class SoftwareSerial */ 
SoftwareSerial bt(2,3); /* (Rx,Tx) */  

void setup() {
  bt.begin(9600); /* Define baud rate for software serial communication */
  Serial.begin(9600); /* Define baud rate for serial communication */
}

void loop() {
  if (bt.available()) { /* If data is available on serial port */
    Serial.write(bt.read()); /* Print character received on to the serial monitor */
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Comment: There is no "female" with bluetooth, just master and slave. Maybe you need to first configure the HC-05 to work as a slave device. Did you try that?

Comment: @chrisl Perhaps he has the same experience like me. Master = female, slave = male (me). Sorry I couldn't resist. :-) I'm also curirous about the button that blinks.  And now seriously: (Karan wagh) The HC05 has to be configured. Here is a link that might help: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/electropeak/getting-started-with-hc-05-bluetooth-module-arduino-e0ca81

Comment: I tried that but got no success @chrisl

Comment: Then please also explain what you tried and how it didn't work. We need more information, or we are not able to help

Comment: we followed this https://www.instructables.com/Connecting-HC-05-Bluetooth-Module-to-Arduino/  @chrisl